# Shortening Reference

Tags: bibdesk

I want to reference

```
[Was97] L. Washington, Introduction to cyclotomic fields, Springer, New York, 1997.
```

in my text. However, using Bibdesk, it autogenerates Was97 for me. How may I change that to [W97] or in fact, to anything else?

Comment: `Bibdesk` just provides you the bib-file. You have to change the style of your bibliography (`alpha` might be what you need). Do you use `biber` or `bibtex`?

Comment: Now I'm confused. I don't seem to be using either? I received a list of publications from my supervisor in a file with .bib and then imported in straight into Bibdesk.

Comment: But in the end you want to create a LaTeX document, where you link these references? If so, please prodive a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so I can see what you are using.

Comment: I get it now. I'm using bibtext:

@book{washington,
 Address = {New York},
 Author = {Washington, L.},
 Date-Modified = {2014-08-07 10:39:32 +0000},
 Publisher = {Springer},
 Title = {Introduction to cyclotomic fields},
 Year = {1997}}
Why not write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is your bib-File, but I assume, that you are using bibtex as told.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{washington,
      Address = {New York},
        Author = {Washington, L.},
        Publisher = {Springer},
        Title = {Introduction to cyclotomic fields},
        Year = {1997},
        }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} % change this style
\end{document}
```

You might want to have a look e.g. [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) to see examples of the different styles.

If you want your references like [W97] this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131878/31323) might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to shorten the citation callouts, you should switch from your current bibliography style -- likely `alpha` -- to a numeric citation style.

To make the switch, you have to locate the `\bibliographystyle`  instruction in your tex file. I'm guessing it currently says

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

Change this to either `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` or `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the changes. You will then get citation callouts, e.g, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.