# Biblatex / Second author's name initialized

Tags: biblatex, author

Is there a way to automatically initialize the second name of an author? In my example: not "Peter Eli" but "Peter E.". (Obviously I know I can just initialize in the bibtex file).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{gordon2004,
  title = {Continental divide: {{Ernst Cassirer}} and {{Martin Heidegger}} at {{Davos}}, 1929 -- an allegory of intellectual history},
  author = {Gordon, Peter Eli},
  date = {2004},
  journaltitle = {Modern Intellectual History},
  shortjournal = {Modern Intellectual History},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {219--248},
  publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
  issn = {1479-2451}
}
@article{gordon2005,
  title = {Myth and modernity: {{Cassirer}}'s critique of {{Heidegger}}},
  author = {Gordon, Peter Eli},
  date = {2005},
  journaltitle = {New German Critique},
  number = {94},
  pages = {127--168}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, maxbibnames=2, minbibnames=1, maxsortnames=2, scauthorsbib=false, doi=false, isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, citepages=suppress]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{gordon2004} e \cite{gordon2005}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `giveninits=true`  Will produce "Gordon, P. E."  but I am afraid that initialize except the first name need a deep hack. Check if [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126265/11604) help.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131869/biblatex-how-to-abbreviate-names-in-citations-only-get-say-first-letters-of

Comment: Understood. I guess for the time being I will have to abbreviate in the bib file if I want to abbreviate only one name. Thanks!

Comment: `biblatex` (like BibTeX) has no concept of a middle name. First and middle names are all treated as `given` names and can only all be abbreviated or all given in full (as-is). There are tricks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187684/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126061/35864 and linked discussions, but they all come with downsides. In theory you could use the extended name format and define a new middle name, but that implies heavy changes to both the input in the `.bib` file as well as all name formatting macros on the LaTeX side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

biblatex and biber allow you to customise the data model name parts to add whichever name parts you need. So, to implement a real middle name so that you can control its initials properly:

```
% First add middle name as a real name part in the data model
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,middle}
\end{filecontents}
  
% Use the biber extended name format to specify the middle name explicltly
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{gordon2004,
  title = {Continental divide: {{Ernst Cassirer}} and {{Martin Heidegger}} at {{Davos}}, 1929 -- an allegory of intellectual history},
  author = {family=Gordon, given=Peter, middle=Eli},
  date = {2004},
  journaltitle = {Modern Intellectual History},
  shortjournal = {Modern Intellectual History},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {219--248},
  publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
  issn = {1479-2451}
}
@article{gordon2005,
  title = {Myth and modernity: {{Cassirer}}'s critique of {{Heidegger}}},
  author = {family=Gordon, given=Peter, middle=Eli},
  date = {2005},
  journaltitle = {New German Critique},
  number = {94},
  pages = {127--168}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
% Adding a namepart to the datamodel automatically creates the relevant
% <part>inits package option:
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, maxbibnames=2, minbibnames=1, maxsortnames=2, scauthorsbib=false, doi=false, isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, citepages=suppress,datamodel=\jobname,middleinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Expand the name printing macro so that middle name is now a separate argument
\newcommand{\mkbibcompletenamegivenmiddlefamily}{\mkbibcompletename}
\newbibmacro*{name:given-middle-family}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#4#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#4#1}%
  \mkbibcompletenamegivenmiddlefamily{%
    \ifdefvoid{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
    \ifdefvoid{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibnamemiddle{#3}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
    \ifdefvoid{#4}
      {}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{#4}\isdot
       \ifprefchar
         {}
         {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
    \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
    \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}}


% Adjust the name format to pass the correct middle name format depending
% on package options. \if<namepart>inits is automatically created when
% adding a name part to the datamodel.
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-middle-family}
\DeclareNameFormat{given-middle-family}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\ifmiddleinits
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-middle-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartmiddlei}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-middle-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartmiddle}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      }
    {\ifmiddleinits
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-middle-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartmiddlei}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-middle-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartmiddle}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
\cite{gordon2004}\\
\cite{gordon2005}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly