# How to cite full first name when giveninits=true?

Tags: biblatex, citing

In [Citing author's full name in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/citing-authors-full-name-in-biblatex), lockstep proposes the following solution to typeset author names

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Knu86,
        author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\hypersetup{citecolor=SlateBlue2, citebordercolor=SlateBlue2, colorlinks=true}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage[giveninits=true]{biblatex}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfirstlast}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}%
    \printnames{labelname}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorlastfirst}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}%
    \printnames{labelname}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
    
    \citeauthorfirstlast{Knu86}
    
    \citeauthorlastfirst{Knu86}
    
    \citeauthor{Knu86}
    
    \cite{Knu86}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

However, this solution does not meet the following requirements

1. Sometimes, it is possible we want to typeset the name as

> Donald Knuth

(the full first name should appear although we use the option `giveninits=true`)

2. The name of the author must be linked to the bibitem in the bibliography

Comment: The cleanest way is to augment the data model with middle names so that you can control initials separately for first names and middle names. See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693143/biblatex-second-authors-name-initialized/693345#693345